# Gerrit project access allows users to remove the users from gerrit project

Tags: gerrit

**My Gerrit Version is -2.10.2**

Regarding an Gerrit group (Delete user permission), I am the Gerrit administrator, I have user add/delete permission for Gerrit groups. Today I noticed that even the users who all have access to Gerrit group, are also able to remove users from Gerrit group. I thought, only admin can perform the manage groups and users permissions, whereas it is working for user as well. I have checked the project it has configured the access from “Rights Inherit From: All-Projects” also “Project All-Projects”  it has below settings.

**Global Capabilities**

```
Administrate Server -
Allow -  Administrators

Priority -
Batch -  Non-Interactive Users

Stream Events - 
Allow - Non-Interactive Users
```

Could you let me know where I can configure the permission, So that user should is not allowed to remove the user from Gerrit group. Only Gerrit administrator need to have users add & delete permission from Gerrit groups.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "remove the users from gerrit project"?

Comment: Means users able to remove gerrit project access permission from group.

Comment: So you mean "remove members from Gerrit groups", right?

Comment: Yes, Remove members from gerrit project group permission should be with only administrator.

Comment: No, the owners group rules who can add/remove users to a Gerrit group. I just added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following:

- Click on the "General" tab of some group.
- Look at the group in the "Owners" field

All users that are members of the owner group (or members of one of its sub-groups) has the permission to add and remove users to original group.

Put the administrator group (or other group you want) in this field and click on the "Change owner" button.

Comment: Thank you very much Marcelo...! It is working as expected. Thanks once again.

Comment: By default, Gerrit sets the _Group_ as the _owner of the group_, so any member of a group becomes a "manager" of his/her groups and can add/remove members.

Comment: Yes you are right Gonen. I have changed group owner to gerrit admin. Thank you.